# IP address pool in Java Security Exceptions

Tags: java, java-security

There is a way to put some address pool in Java Security Exceptions (Java 8 and higher)?
In Java 7 I can add eg. 192.168.* to the exception list. In Java 8 this doesn't work.
(BTW. Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Does it work for a single IP in your case ?

Comment: Yes. If I add single IP it's working but I have a lot of these IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the exception site list in a text editor (eg Notepad++). I used Excel to auto-fill a range (eg https://192.168.1.1 -> https://192.168.1.255). I then copied and pasted this into the exception.sites file.

C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites
The exceptions then show up in the Java Control Panel exception list.